# Automate FFMPEG

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg, automation, editing

I"m using ffmpeg to create video clips. I want to automate the process and save the  clips without manually giving names to each file being saved. Here is the code I have. It will create and save the clip but only with an extension and not a name.

```
@echo off 
cd /d %~dp0

set /p place="Enter location: " %=%

set /p time="Enter time: " %=%

for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.mp4') do set FileName=%%~na

ffmpeg -i "%place%" -ss %time% -codec copy -t 10 %FileName%.mp4
```

I'm sure there's a simple solution but I can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: this will process only one file...?

Comment: what name you to assign to the created clip?

Comment: What are you entering in for the location?  The `-i` option is for the input file name.  Search SO using these parameters `[batch-file] ffmpeg` and I bet you will find your answer. Or at least understand how to automate FFMPEG.

Comment: For what are the %=% ?

Comment: Do not use variable name `time` as this is system-reserved!

Comment: I changed the variable name but after the file rendered wasn't playable

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below.

```
@echo off 
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd /d %~dp0

set /p place="Enter location: "

set /p time="Enter time: "

for /F %%a in ('dir /b *.mp4') do (

    set FileName=%%~na

)

ffmpeg -i "!place!" -ss !time! -codec copy -t 10 "!FileName!.mp4"
```

Comment: This is working  @echo off 
cd /d %~dp0
set /p myFile="Enter location: " %=%
set /p time="Enter time: " %=%
set name=%RANDOM%

ffmpeg -i "%myFile%" -ss %time% -codec copy -t 10 %myFile%-%RANDOM%.mp4
pause

Comment: Great that you figured it out :)